# Contact Form will only display if I remove the 'zoom' property; need a solution

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, zooming

I setup a static html landing page; displays perfectly in Chorme, Safari, and Firefox. However, I cannot get the embeded MailChimp contact form name and email fields to display when I use the zoom property; as soon as I remove it, the inputs show up too large and out of place which is why I used the zoom property in the first place.

Why would this cause an error? Is there anyway to rememdy this odd problem?

url: http://comingsoon.veteranbrewingcompany.com/

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to address why the form is so large. Various styles are causing it to be so, such as

```
#mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group input {
font-size: 40px;
}

#mc_embed_signup .button {
background: url("http://themicroscopeguy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/submit2.png");
width: 207px;
height: 92px;
}
```

So, you have big font sizes set, and the submit button is quite a large image. You can address all that via CSS. You don't need an image for the subbmit button, as you can easily style a normal button with CSS.